# Onsend reload menu from controller to hide menu items

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, cordova, onsen-ui

I have a sliding-menu that has some list items. I want to change the visibility of some of the items according to the signed in user type.

I have 3 controllers: LoginController, AppController and I just made a MenuController.

This is my menu:

```
<ons-template id="menu.html">
    <ons-page ng-controller="menuController" ng-init="initMenu()">
      <ons-list>
        <ons-list-item modifier="tappable" onclick="menu.setMainPage('navigator.html', {closeMenu: true})">
          <ons-icon icon="ion-home" style="padding-bottom:2px;"></ons-icon>  Home
        </ons-list-item>
        <ons-list-item modifier="tappable" ng-hide="{{isTypeA}}" onclick="menu.setMainPage('Page1.html', {closeMenu: true})">
          <ons-icon icon="ion-clipboard" style="padding-bottom:2px;"></ons-icon>  Page 1
        </ons-list-item>
        <ons-list-item modifier="tappable" ng-hide="{{isTypeA}}" onclick="menu.setMainPage('Page2.html', {closeMenu: true})">
          <ons-icon icon="ion-loop" style="padding-bottom:2px;"></ons-icon>  Page 2
        </ons-list-item>

        <ons-list-item modifier="tappable" ng-hide="{{isTypeA}}" onclick="menu.setMainPage('Page3.html', {closeMenu: true})">
          <ons-icon icon="ion-compose" style="padding-bottom:2px;"></ons-icon>  Page 3
        </ons-list-item>
        <ons-list-item modifier="tappable" onclick="menu.setMainPage('Page4.html', {closeMenu: true})">
          <ons-icon icon="ion-gear-a" style="padding-bottom:2px;"></ons-icon>  Settings
        </ons-list-item>
      </ons-list>
  </ons-page>
</ons-template>
```

When signing in a user, the menu controller loads first, so the init function is already done. Then when the user keys in his credentials and presses LOGIN, I use a service to set the license type in a variable, but then when the app loads, it's already too late.

How to fix this issue, so right after the login, the menu gets initialized again and the ng-hide will correctly hide / show all the necessary elements?

Answer (score 0):

You need to write an menuList array as a scope property which contain field such as showMenu
And a function to update your menu field (showMenu) after logging in

```
function menuController ($scope){
  // init menu
  $scope.menuList = [{
       showMenu: true,
       menuPage: 'Page1.html',
       ...
    }, 
    {  showMenu: true,
       menuPage: 'Page2.html',
       ...
    }
    , ...];

  // call this function after logging in
  function updateMenuAfterLogin() {
      menuList.foreach (function(menu){
          if ('someCondition') {
              menu.showMenu= false;
          }
      }
  }

}
```

Then write a ng-repeat to render your list:

```
      <ons-list>
        <ons-list-item modifier="tappable" ng-repeat= "menuItem in menuList"  ng-hide="{{menuItem.show}}" onclick="menu.setMainPage({{menuItem.menuPage}}, {closeMenu: true})">
          <ons-icon icon="ion-home" style="padding-bottom:2px;"></ons-icon>  Home
       </ons-list-item>
     </ons-list>
```

Answer (score 0):

I see 2 ways to solve this problem:

1. > How to fix this issue, so right after the login, the menu gets initialized again and the ng-hide will correctly hide / show all the necessary elements?

   This is the first way - after you login you can just reload the menu page `menu.setMenuPage('menu.html')` or anything similar which will explicitly make the change.
2. Alternatively since you are saying that

   > I use a service to set the license type in a variable

   You could just make that variable visible to the view and use it for your `ng-show/ng-hide`. Here's a simple [**Demo**](http://codepen.io/IliaSky/pen/Gqgwym?editors=1010) to see it in action.

   Basically that's what we get from angular's 2 way data binding - we can even toggle the value between `true` and `false` and the items will update accordingly.

The choice is yours. I think the second one feels closer to "The Angular Way", but if you prefer setting things explicitly that's also fine, since that has worked for us long before Angular was invented.